# I want to Extract data from a page with <tr>

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping

Here's what i have done, but i'm still getting error

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get(\"https://www.aia.org/firm-directory?query=architect\")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,\"html.parser\")
html_page=soup.find('tbody')
rows=html_page.find('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    print(cols)"
```

Comment: Hi CodingVyper, could you please be more specific about the error, you can for instance post the stacktrace.

Comment: Hi, did you check the html output of your request? You will not find any table there.

Comment: true. i didn't find any table